# Running the CraftBukkit Server for minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I recently download Craft Bukkit for running a multiplayer minecraft server, and according to tutorial I created a run.bat file in the note pad with following code to run the server

java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
PAUSE

and according to tutorial's the server should start but insted of it the following error message appears
[image]

I dont know what is wrong cause the same thing happens with other server builds i try to run so please help me.

Comment: Is the crafbukkit.jar file beside the run.bat file, or is it in a different folder?

Comment: sir it is in the same folder @SevenSidedDie

Comment: My guess is that you might have named the file `craftbukkit.jar.jar` due to Windows hiding the extension. Try removing the `.jar` from the name of the file and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to rename the downloaded craftbukkit file from

craftbukkit-1.x.x-xx.x.jar

to

craftbukkit.jar

The .bat command expects a file called craftbukkit.jar, if it doesn't find it, you get that error.

Also check what @SevenSidedDie said.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i fixed the problem it was the name problem you don't have to change it to craftbukkit.jar but just to craftbukkit

Comment: Ah, I see. You seem to have the "file extensions" disabled, so when you renamed the file to "craftbukkit.jar", the files name actually is "craftbukkit.jar.jar"...

Comment: yeah true really messed me up for like a month bubt thanks for the help can you help in the other ques i asked

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps:

1. Download Craftbukkit
2. Once downloaded, place into a empty new folder (name of your choice)
3. Rename the craftbukkit.jar file to craftbukkit.jar
4. Drag your .bat into the same folder as your craftbukkit
5. run the .bat file

Answer (score -2):

rename craftbukkit (perferably bukkuit) than edit the end to .jar (bukkit.jar)

Comment: How will renaming it to `bukkit.jar` help?